# QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment.

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing, qt4

I saw there is one same thread: [OpenCv Error in C Wrapper for imread: QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606144/opencv-error-in-c-wrapper-for-imread-qnativeimage-unable-to-attach-to-shared-m)     That thread was posted about 4 months ago. No any answer. So I re-post one.

I ran this code on eclipse luna on ubuntu14.04.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat img = imread("/home/tqjustc/Pictures/2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    imshow("opencvtest", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

But there is an error.

```
init done 
opengl support available 
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
```

Can any one help solve this problem ?

Comment: Please do not post repeat questions about the same thing. If you have more details, add them to an existing question. Your use of the term "thread" implies that you think of this as a discussion forum. SO is most definitely not a discussion forum, and attempts to use it as such are invalid. What you *should* have done is to upvote the original question, and perhaps edit-in your shorter testcase (leaving the other one intact).

Answer (score 3):

You should update Java to openjdk-8-jdk. I had the samo issue here.
[Python error message in PyCharm: Unable to attach to shared memory segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469060/python-error-message-in-pycharm-unable-to-attach-to-shared-memory-segment/33473784#33473784)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for `QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment` and found this [bug report with a solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/retext/+bug/1026025).

Comment: Thanks, but when I ran 'LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 retext' in terminal, it asked me to install retext, and I installed it. Then When I ran the command again, it opened a new txt file ..... and the problem still is not solved. When I resized the image size to be small, e.g. 500*500, then the error disappears. but for too large image size, the error still exists.