# Python error message in PyCharm: Unable to attach to shared memory segment

Tags: python, ubuntu

I started writing my code in Ubuntu 15.04 in PyCharm and Python 2.7. Meanwhile, I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 and PyCharm 4.5.4 CE. Now when I run my code I get this error:

```
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 

(python2.7:8078): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28 (No space left on device)
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
```

Although it doesn't happen every time I run my code. What could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this error with an old Openjdk package. After sudo apt-get update and upgrade this error disappeared.

Comment: Yes. I upgraded to java jdk 8 `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` and then selected it for default `sudo update-alternatives --config java`. Than you can check java version `java -version`. It should say something like `openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"`

Comment: For those of us on RHEL/Centos:

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64`
`sudo alternatives --config java`
(select something like /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java)